# PieChart legend options

Tags: flutter, charts

Hi community I am new in Flutter and I am using the `syncfusion_flutter_charts` library to create a Pie Chart, I would like to know if there is a way for the list shown in the legend at the beginning to appear all deselected or if there is a way for a legend to include an option to deselect/select all list items shown in the legend.

Here is my code:

```dart
SfCircularChart(
  title: ChartTitle(text: 'PieChart'),
  tooltipBehavior: _tooltipBehavior,
  legend: const Legend(isVisible: true),
  series: <CircularSeries>[
    PieSeries<ChartPieData, String>(
      enableTooltip: true,
      dataSource: pieData,
      xValueMapper: (ChartPieData data, _) => data.category,
      yValueMapper: (ChartPieData data, _) => data.value,
    ),
  ],
)
```

And here is my output:
[image]